# Adding multiple collection into a collection

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am new to blue prism.

I want to add multiple collections in my collection.
Business Scenerio:

I have multiple sheets in an excel file. I have converted a sheet data into an collection. So I have multiple collections for that excel.

Now I want to create a Parent collection and add all child collections to it. How can I achieve this in BluePrism.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your main collection with a single column of type 'Collection'. Then each time you retrieve collection from Excel use 'Add Row' action from the internal 'Collections' object and then a 'Calculation' to the parent collection.

If you want, you can even make it more compact and add the row first and store the collection from the 'Excel' command directly to the new row.